# Way around impossibility to overload parameterless functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading, virtual

I have a question concerning overloading virtual functions in the context of inheriting in 2 different classes from the same base class, that both require the same function, but for a different data type + the function has no parameters, so apparently cannot be overloaded.

Example:

```
class Base {

    virtual int get_member(){};
    virtual char get_member(){};

};

class Derived1: public Base {

    int get_member(){return member;}

    private:

        int member = 0;

};

class Derived2: public Base {

    char get_member(){return member;}

    private:

        char member = 'a';
}
```

This does not compile, and I kind of see why, but not really. But my actual question is a conceptual one, namely how to approach such a problem *instead*, as overloading does not work.

Comment: You can always go with getIntMember, getStringMember;

Comment: You have to give them different names, or possibly make it a template. However, templates + virtual is tricky.

Comment: Hm, ok thanks. Had thought there would be an elegant solution.

Comment: You already showed that you know you can't overload by return type, which is correct. However you didn't ask us your *real* question (why do you think you need to overload on return type) so we can help solve your real problem.

Comment: Well yes, because this example was close to my real problem. I have two inheriting classes with 1 member each that has a different type from the other. The example is just a simplified version of my real code, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html):

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
class Base {
  public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    boost::any getValue() { return m_value; }
  private:
    boost::any m_value;  
};

// for derived classes, you really do not need a new getValue()
```

Comment: Hm, I need to stick to the most basic libraries... so can't use that :/

I tried the template solution, but don't get that to work.

I guess I will just go with the simplest but kinda ugly solution of declaring a separate function per data type.